# Counting combinations of values in table of values excel?

Tags: excel, combinations, counting

I have a table of values with each value in a different cell

e.g.

```
2   9   12  19  41  45  14  39
12  14  19  27  39  40  30  44
6   9   13  15  16  41  7   20
8   16  14  34  13  44  5   15
10  11  20  24  27  36  9   41
```

Is there a way to find which pairs of numbers are most common.

i.e.

13 & 15 appear 2 times

14 & 44 appear 2 times

24 & 27 appear 1 time

I was hoping for a formula as the table has over a hundred rows in it so would be time consuming to count manually.

Comment: Use `COUNTIF` ?

Comment: I suspect you'll have to use VBA to build up a `Dictionary` of all the combinations as you parse through the data. If I'm understanding your question, your data produces pairs starting with `2,9`, `9,12`, `12,19`, etc. The pair becomes the key to the `Dictionary`, then you can just count the occurrences as you go.

Comment: Do they have to appear in the same row? Are all the numbers 1 or 2 digits?

Comment: How are you defining "pairs"?  2 values next to each other horizontally, next to each other vertically, next to each other treating the whole range as one long string??  In order for us to give you a good answer, we need a clear definition.

Comment: @FrankBall The 2 values are next to each other horizontally, but do not have to be adjacent. So could be the 1st and 5th values in the row.

Comment: @TomSharpe They must be in the same row, and all values are between 1 and 45. So they will be a mixture of 1 digit and 2 digit values

Comment: You could do it by formula, but I think you'd have to make a list or table of all the combinations 1,2 1,3 ...2,3 2,4 ....44,45 that's nearly 1000 different pairs then evaluate each one of them and sort them by frequency.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you would want would be the one for the row totals of a pair of numbers in A2 and B2:

```
=SUM(MMULT(--($E$2:$L$6=A2),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(E:L))^0)*MMULT(--($E$2:$L$6=B2),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(E:L))^0))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

There will be formulas for for listing distinct pairs up to a certain number out there - I used

```
=IF(ROW()=2,1,IF(B1<45,A1,A1+1))
```

for A2 and

```
=IF(B1<45,B1+1,2+COUNTIF(B$1:B1,45))
```

for B2.

[image]

If you scroll down this list you can see that 13,16 occurs twice as well as 13,15.

[image]

9,41 occurs three times.

Note - I am assuming the numbers are like lottery numbers and any one number can only occur once in a row. The formula could easily be modified to account for duplicates within a row.